# How to export data to local system from snowflake cloud data warehouse?

Tags: database, cloud, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am using snowflake cloud datawarehouse, which is like teradata that hosts data. I am able run queries and get results on the web UI itself. But I am unclear how can one export the results to a local PC so that we can report based on the data.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have 2 options which both use sfsql which is based on henplus.  The first option is to export the result of your query to a S3 staging file as shown below:

```
CREATE STAGE my_stage URL='s3://loading/files/' CREDENTIALS=(AWS_KEY_ID=‘****' AWS_SECRET_KEY=‘****’);
COPY INTO @my_stage/dump
FROM  (select * from orderstiny limit 5) file_format=(format_name=‘csv' compression=‘gzip'');
```

The other option is to capture the sql result into a file.

### test.sql:

```
set-property column-delimiter ","; 
set-property sql-result-showheader off;
set-property sql-result-showfooter off;

select current_date() from dual;
```

$ ./sfsql < test.sql > result.txt

For more details and help, login to your snowflake account and access the online documentation or post your question to Snowflake support via the Snowflake support portal which is accessible through the Snowflake help section.  Help -> Support Portal.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a COPY command to export a table (or query results) into a file on S3 (using "stage" locations), and then a GET command to save it onto your local filesystem. You can only do it from the "sfsql" Snowflake command line tool (not from web UI).

Search the documentation for "unloading", you'll find more info there.

Answer (score 2):

You can directly download the data from Snowflakes to Local Filesystem without staging to S3 or redirecting via unix pipe

1. Use **COPY INTO** to load table data to table staging
   https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-location.html

   > snowsql$> copy into @%test_table/result/data_ from test_table
   >   file_format = (TYPE ='[FILE_TYPE]' compression='[COMPRESSION_TYPE]');
2. Use **GET** command to download data from table staging to Local FS
   https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/sql/get.html

   > snowsql$> get @%test_table/result/data_ file:///tmp/;